# Hive's string parsing using regular expression with RegexSerDe

Tags: regex, parsing, hadoop, hive, string-parsing

I'm trying to use RegexSerDe to parse a string input to different attributes of a table with Hive. The original string is in the format of

> "...  (A; B) (X; Y);"

And the output I expected is

> foo = "A; B" and bar = "X; Y"

(as two separate attributes in the table).  The regular expression I used as "input.regex" is

```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test(
...
foo STRING,
bar STRING
)ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "... \(([^\)]*?)\) \(([^\)]*?)\)",
"output.format.string" = "...%4$s %5$s"
)
stored as textfile;
```

which parses my string correctly on other web tools I found. But SerDe wasn't be able to match the string (return null). Trying to use double backslash doesn't help.
I also tried to use some other expression like

> "input.regex" = "... \(.*\) \(.*\)"

for the last two parentheses, HIVE output the parsed string as

> "foo = "(A; B) (X"  and bar = "Y)"

, as it splits my string by the last space. I guess I didn't handle my right parentheses correctly but I wan't be able to find out the correct way.

Comment: your question representation is quite confusing. format/beautify it and highlight wherever needed , like regex used,record sample etc.

Comment: You missed output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s

Comment: @ramisetty.vijay sorry I accidentally deleted them when I posted it.